# How to do webpage scraping for multiple tags

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to extract "href" link form a webpage to my excel sheet based on the value available in sheet. I am successful by doing the same for one value, but I am unable to loop the same.

Below is the code for one value which runs fine:

```
Dim X As String
X = ActiveCell.Value ' I have selected the cell "A1" before even starting the macro
Set ElementCol = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each link In ElementCol
If link.innerHTML = Jesus Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = link.href ' I will have the value in the "B1"
End If
Next
```

Here is the screenshot

[image: Example]

Now when I try to loop the code runs but it gives me the same value in all the cells
This is the code I tried :

```
Dim intRowCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim X As String
X = ActiveCell.Value
intRowCount = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To intRowCount
Set ElementCol = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each link In ElementCol
If link.innerHTML = X Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = link.href
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
Next
Next i
```

Here is the screenshot

[image: Example2]

I hope I explained the situation in a understandable way, Kindly pardon me for any errors. Also the link in the picture is sample !!!

Below is the reworked code which worked:

```
X = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To X
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Dim Y As String
Jesus = ActiveCell.Value
Set ElementCol = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each link In ElementCol
If link.innerHTML = Y Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = link.href
End If
Next
Next i
```

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid using `ActiveCell`, instead simply reference the cells in full. You've also created a loop with `i` but not referred to this.

The main issue is that you are setting the value of `X` outside of the loop and then comparing the link to this value which will remain the same for every iteration.

Try the following:

```
Dim eRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim ws as Worksheet

Set ws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("SheetName")

eRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set ElementCol = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

For i = 1 To eRow
    For Each link In ElementCol
        If link.innerHTML = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
            ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = link.href
        End If
    Next
Next i
```

Comment: I am SORRY for the delay in response !! Actually we had a cyclone attack and all our internet and mobile networks were down !!! I thank you for your immediate response, however I am so dumb to understand your coding, so I copy, pasted your code but it work !!! However I did understand form your advice "setting the Value X outside of the loop and then comparing the link" So I redid my code and it worked !!!

Comment: And I pasted the working code in the "Original post section"  Thank you I appricate your timely help